# JAX-RS REST service + EJB on WildFly 10, always adds no-cache HTTP header in responses

Tags: ejb, jax-rs, wildfly, cache-control, http-caching

I have wrote a stateless EJB that provides a rest service.
I am working with the Wildfly 10 application server and developing with the Netbeans IDE.

I have tried to cache the return values of few methods for few hours by adding a max-age header in the http-response of the service methods. Please consider this is a simplified version of my bean:

```
    @Stateless
    @DeclareRoles({"role1","role2"})
    @RolesAllowed({"role1","role2"})
    @Path("api-dummy")
    public class DummyApiREST {

        @EJB
        private StuffFacade stuffFacade;

        @GET
        @Path("get-stuff")
        @Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
        public Response findStuff() {
            Stuff stuff = stuffFacade.getStuff();
            Response.ResponseBuilder builder = Response.status(Response.Status.OK).entity(stuff);
            Utils.setCacheHeader(maxAgeSeconds, builder);
            return builder.build();
        }
   }
```

And the setCacheHeader method:

```
private static Response.ResponseBuilder setCacheHeader(int maxAgeSeconds, Response.ResponseBuilder builder) {
        CacheControl cc = new CacheControl();
        cc.setNoCache(false);
        cc.setNoStore(false);
        cc.setMaxAge(maxAgeSeconds);
        cc.setPrivate(true);
        builder.cacheControl(cc);
        return builder;
 }
```

But the returned response of "get-stuff" always contains a duplicate of the Cache-Control header; the duplicate header contains no-cache directives (the is also a Pragma header):

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Expires: 0
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
Cache-Control: no-transform, max-age=60, private
X-Powered-By: Undertow/1
Server: WildFly/10
Pragma: no-cache
Date: Thu, 13 Apr 2017 15:11:17 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Type: application/json
```

I suppose the problem is caused by a default behaviour--or filter-- for the JAX-RS services in my EJBs. My questions are:

- Is there a better way to set the max-age and enable caching in JAX-RS + EJB?
- Is there a way to disable this no-cache default behaviour? (OR in other words,  where is this usually configured?)
- ..and..what is wrong in my solution? :-)

NOTE: Perhaps it is not related, I have configured a jdbc security-domain and users authenticate and principal(s) work well.

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the solution.
By default Wildfly (and I think JBoss too) adds the *no-cache* directives to **all** the **private resources** (resources that needs authentication).

You have to change the configuration in *standalone.xml* file, by adding an attribute *disable-caching*-* to the *server-container* tag:

```
<servlet-container name="default" disable-caching-for-secured-pages="false">
                    <jsp-config/>
                    <websockets/>
</servlet-container>
```

In this way no more *Pragma* and *nocache* directives will be added to responses and the code I posted in my question, it simply works as expected.

**EDIT**: Remind, when requests for private resources, at the same URL, have to return different contents to different users you have to:

- add the *private* header to that responses, for your reverse proxy to
  not cache that content OR in alternative..
- ..left the *nocache* header there for that responses